# Slide out sidebar in Blogger

Tags: slide, blogger, sidebar, out

I'd like to have my sidebar slide out of my blog with the click of a button. I've only been able to find this for Dynamic Views but surely it can be done with the right code! My site is bhyphen.com and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple.

This is how I did it in my static magazine template. You can check out a live preview of what the sidebar looks like here: http://kreatief-staticmagazinetemplate.blogspot.ch/

First you need to add a new section:

```
<div id='sidebar'>
  <a href="#search" class="toggle-link">x</a>
  <b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebarsection'>
  </b:section>
</div><!--/sidebar-->
<a class='toggle-link' href='#sidebar'><i class='fa fa-plus fa-lg'/></a>
```

So we have a container and a anchor, which will toggle the sidebar.

Then register the section so that you can add widgets to it.

I do use font-awesome in the button, so place

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

within the `<head>` of your page.

When the button is clicked, we will toggle an active class on the menu, so for that I used a little bit of jQuery (it's best if you search for the closing body tag (`</body>`) and add the following directly above.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'/>
<!-- toggle active class -->
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".toggle-link").click(function(){
            $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active");
            $(".toggle-link").toggleClass("active");
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Then just finish off with CSS.

Place that in the CSS section, above `]]></b:skin>`

I did already write the variable definition for the template designer, so I'll just add it as well, put that to the other variable definitions

```
<Group description="Sidebar and Toggle" selector="#sidebar, .toggle-link">
    <Variable name="sidebar.bg" description="Sidebar Background Color" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#ffffff"/>
    <Variable name="sidebar.border" description="Sidebar Border Color" type="color" default="#333333" value="#333333"/>
    <Variable name="box.link.color" description="Box Link Color" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#ffffff"/>
    <Variable name="box.link.bg" description="Box Link Background" type="color" default="#333333" value="#333333"/>
    <Variable name="box.hover.bg" description="Box Link Hover Background" type="color" default="#000000" value="#000000"/>
</Group>
```

If you don't want to use the variables, just replace all of the variable names with colors of your choice.

```
/*  Sidebar
/*-------------------------------*/
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 300px;
    right: -304px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    background-color: $(sidebar.bg);
    border-left: 4px solid $(sidebar.border);
    z-index: 15;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.sidebar{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 5% !important;
}

.widget{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.toggle-link.active,
#sidebar.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-304px, 0px);
    transform: translate(-304px, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.toggle-link.active i{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.toggle-link {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: $(box.link.bg);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 15;
    color: $(box.link.color);
}


#sidebar .toggle-link {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
    #sidebar .toggle-link {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        right: -270px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }  
}

.toggle-link:hover {
    background: $(box.hover.bg);
}

.toggle-link i {
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
    transition: 1s ease;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
```

And that's it.